# Access and modify $scope from ng-include

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-include

**EDIT**
I just realized why it's probably not working, though I don't know how to resolve this.  The include is on my main HTML page, not within my ng-view.  That's probably why $parent isn't working, because technically the ng-view is the parent of the include.  So it's:

```
<body>
 <div ng-view></div>
 <div ng-include="menuPath"></div>
</body>
```

I need to access the ng-view scope from the ng-include scope.

I've created a plunker to illustrate the issue
http://plnkr.co/WtVdkWKXaPWCfHJPLf1q

**Original Question**

Due to restrictions outside my control I have to include all my menus for each page using ng-include.  I'm trying to figure out how to access and modify the parent scope from the ng-include.  I've found several threads about it, but the examples are all gone.  It seems like it's something simple but I can't seem to find the answer.

As an example, on my main page I have the following data in Scope

```
{
  "Statuses":
  [
    {"ID":"1", "Name":"Open"},
    {"ID":"2", "Name":"Closed"}
  ],
  "StatusID":"1"
}
```

In my ng-include I'm trying to do the following:

```
<select ng-model="StatusID" ng-options="x.ID as x.Name for x in Statuses"></select>
```

It doesn't get the data though as the ng-include apparently creates it's own Scope.

Comment: Try putting your object in a service and sharing that way.

Comment: Could you point me to an example?  Doesn't have to be exact.  I'm still a little new to this.

Comment: Can you show how you are setting the `$scope.Statuses` in your controller.  That might be the issue.

Comment: I know the scope is set correctly on the parent page because I'm loading data on the main page from the scope values.

Comment: With an ng-view, the controllers are automatically swapped.  In the ng-include, the view is set but the controllers are never swapped (or even set).  That is the reason it is not updating the view for the ng-include.  If you create separate directives for each menu view, you will be able to set different controllers for each.

Comment: In the question you've written `That's probably why $parent isn't working, because technically the ng-view is the parent of the include.` which isn't the case based on the code.  ng-view is not the parent of the include.

Comment: @lucuma I ended up using your original suggestion by wrapping the data in a service.  If you post that as an answer I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the data in a service since they are singleton's and share it across controllers.  Something like this:

```
app.factory('MenuCache', function() {

    var data = {
     };  // your data;

    return data;

});
```

and then it can be injected into your controller(s) thus you won't need to worry about their ancestry:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, MenuCache) {

});
```

** Or, as answer to the preupdated question **

You can do this on your include (see $parent.StatusID) in order to access the parent scope's StatusID.

```
<select ng-model="$parent.StatusID" ng-options="x.ID as x.Name for x in a.Statuses">
```

Demo:  http://plnkr.co/edit/eZUnmZAWobFmw52B3IWh?p=preview

Comment: I used this basic approach with a listener attached to the service so both views could listen for when data changed, and either could prompt the change.

Answer (score 3):

ng-include is one of those directives that will create a child scope. Since it relies on scope inheritance to resolve bindings, then ng-model should have a '.' in it to resolve properly. Otherwise, when StatusID is set by changing the drop down list, it will create a shadow variable on the child scope that is a copy of the variable in parent scope. This breaks the model binding.

You need to set-up something like:

```
<select ng-model="model.StatusID" 
     ng-options="x.ID as x.Name for x in model.Statuses"></select>
```

Where`model` is defined in your parent scope.  This ensures that when the Select list changes, it updates the correct model.

In your parent controller:

```
app.controller('parentCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.model = {
        "Statuses":
         [
             {"ID":"1", "Name":"Open"},
             {"ID":"2", "Name":"Closed"}
         ],
         "StatusID":"1"
    }
});
```

Comment: See above edit, I believe I see why the proposed solutions aren't working.  I modified my question to more accurately portray the situation.

Comment: ng-view, like ng-include, create child scopes. My solution or lucuma's solution should work. Both solutions try to resolve a scope variable using scope inheritance. Something else is going on that maybe we can't see. Are you using an isolated scope somewhere in your scope inheritance tree? That might explain why it's not resolving properly.

Comment: It's very strange that $parent is not defined. Could you post a plunker with some minimal code that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I'll put one together.